# How to solve passing IDs in URL with Symfony

Tags: symfony, path, twig

i'm making an app to make appointments with doctors, and in the template of the patient I need to use the id of the entity doctor in the path because I use it in the code of my controller, and I still can't get the Id of the entity doctor because when i do {{ doctor.id }} nothing appears on my screen, the content is empty.

As a solution I used the email of the doctor in the URL but it is quite ugly.

This is the code of the controller

```
     /**
      * @Route("/patient/ajouter-medecin-favoris/{id}", name="meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris")
      */
      public function ajouterMedecinFavoris(MedecinRepository $repoMedecin, ObjectManager $manager, $id)
      {
        $patient = $this->getUser();

        $medecin = $repoMedecin->findOneById($id);

        $patient->addMedecinsFavori($medecin);

        $manager->persist($patient);

        $manager->flush();

        return $this->RedirectToRoute('accueil');
      }
```

here's the code of the element I use to click on it to redirect on the controller previously

```
<fieldset>
     <h4><a href="{{path('meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris',{id: medecin.id})}}" style="color: black;"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a> Dr. {{ medecin.nom }} {{ medecin.prenom }}</h4>
</fieldset>
```

I expected to be able to use the id of the doctor in the URL but I think when you're logged as an entity you can't get the ID (not the id used to log in) of other users and the content of the variable is empty. But I would know if there's a solution to use the ID because passing the email into the url isn't the solution I want, and I had the same problem on other piece of code where the of other entity is empty.

Here's the code of the controller that send the datas to the view

```
     /**
      * @Route("/patient/medecins-favoris", name="meet_my_doc_afficher_medecin_favoris")
      */
      public function afficherMedecinFavoris()
      {
        $patient = $this->getUser();

        $medecins = $this->getUser()->getMedecinsFavoris();

        return $this->Render('meet_my_doc/afficherLesMedecinsFavoris.html.twig', ['medecins' => $medecins]);
      }
```

Comment: where do you get the medecin object in the template ?

Comment: please show the function that renders the template. it seems like your displaying a medecin that doesn't *have* an id.

Comment: I edited the post, and I checked in database, the medecin does have an ID, I just can't get it into the view when I'm logged as a patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to post the answer just now, but this how it worked for me : medecin inherit from User, so when I'm creating a medecin, it is creating also an User, both with the same Id, and if I want to use the medecin object's Id, I need to edit the getId() and replace the code by parent::getId(), this is the only way I've found to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

{{path('meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris',{(id): medecin.id})}}

Comment: **medecin.id** is empty

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, first controller to receive Medicine Object like this, in this case you dont need to use  $medecin = $repoMedecin->findOneById($id);

```
 /**
  * @Route("/patient/ajouter-medecin-favoris/{id}", name="meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris")
  */
  public function ajouterMedecinFavoris(MedecinRepository $repoMedecin, ObjectManager $manager, Medecin $medecin)
  {
       $patient = $this->getUser();
       $patient->addMedecinsFavori($medecin);

       $manager->persist($patient);
       $manager->flush();

       return $this->RedirectToRoute('accueil');
  }
```

in twig in both cases you do something like this

```
{% for medecin in medecins %}
    <fieldset>
          <h4>
              <a href="{{ path('meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris', {'id': medecin.id }) }}" style="color: black;"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
              Dr. {{ medecin.nom }} {{ medecin.prenom }}
          </h4>
     </fieldset>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How does the controller makes the match between the ID in the URL and the $medecin ?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is how you've pasted it, then I think the issue lies in a typo - in the `afficherMedecinFavoris()` action you pass `medicins` to the view, and inside the view you try to access the id of `medicin`. So either remove the extra `s` in the `afficherMedecinFavoris()` or add that extra `s` to the path id parameter value.

Aside from that, I believe that this should work (under the condition that the identity field for `Medecin` entity is `id`):

```php
/**
 * @Route("/patient/ajouter-medecin-favoris/{id}", name="meet_my_doc_ajouter_medecin_favoris")
 */
public function ajouterMedecinFavoris(Medecin $medecin)
{
    $patient = $this->getUser();
    $patient->addMedecinsFavori($medecin);

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $manager->persist($patient);
    $manager->flush();

    return $this->RedirectToRoute('accueil');
}
```

To know how the `Medecin` entity is available as an argument for the controller read [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

Comment: I didn't paste the whole code of the view it is really big, but the problem does not come from the s because I'm using a for : {% for medecin in medecins %} to extract every row of the tab, and the problem does not come from this method too, because the method works fine with the id in the url, the problem is to make a path with the id of the current medecin into the template, because into the for when I do medecin.id, nothing is printed

Comment: Does the part with `medecin.nom` and `medecin.prenom` shows correctly? Can you paste the `Medecin` class?